# Division in Haskell, still don't get it

Tags: haskell, types, integer, int, division

I still don't understand the division in Haskell. My first intention was to define a funcion like this:

```
piApprox :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => a -> b
piApprox n = 4 * sum [ (-1)^k / (2*k + 1) | k <- [0..n] ]
```

It doesn't work. Then, using the signature:

```
piApprox :: (Fractional a) => Int -> a
```

but it raises again the "Could not deduce" error.

If I run this code in the interpreter to find out what signature is the best, the result is:

```
Prelude> let piApprox n = 4 * sum [ (-1)^k / (2*k + 1) | k <- [0..n] ]
Prelude> :t piApprox
piApprox :: (Fractional a, Integral a) => a -> a
```

which raises "The type variable `a0' is ambiguous" error.

Right now, the only way to make this calculation that I could think of is including the `Ratio` package and then converting to `double` by using `fromRational`.

```
import Data.Ratio
piApprox n = (fromRational) $ 4 * sum [ (-1)^k % (2*k + 1) | k <- [0..n] ]
```

It works, but I don't think that's the best approach.

I also thought that even the input and output types were right in the signature, the intermediate operation `(-1)^k / (2*k + 1)` -- where the division is placed -- might be the problem, so I also defined:

```
piApprox' :: (Fractional a) => Int -> a
piApprox' n = 4 * sum [ (fromIntegral) $ (-1)^k / (2*k + 1) | k <- [0..n] ]
```

with no luck.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You probably mean `Integral` instead of `Integer` on the first line of code.  There is no automatic conversion between types in Haskell, so since the result is of type `b` you need to convert the `a` somewhere, e.g., by using `fromIntegral k` instead of `k`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
piApprox n = 4 * sum [ fromIntegral ((-1)^k) / fromIntegral (2*k + 1) | k <- [0..n] ]
```

The `fromIntegral` function has a type signature of :

`(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`

So it basically converts your Integral type to Num type.

The type of `(/`) is:

`Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, so you have to supply Fractional data to it.

The `fromIntegral` function will exactly achieve this by converting it to a `Num` type which includes `Fractional` types.

Comment: "how can we pass `Num` to `Fractional`"... that's bad wording for a non-OO language. You can't "pass `Num`", you can pass objects of a type that happens to be in the `Num` type class. Haskell doesn't have subtypes, which is what you're probably alluding to. Even then, it would need to be that other way around: "pass `Fractional` to `Num`".

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, I agree with you. How will you rephrase that better ?

Comment: I'd just say "fromIntegral converts integer numbers to numbers of any other `Num` type (including fractional types)". Reading up on the various type classes is something you can do elsewhere.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, Thanks, rephrased it better I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're mixing incompatible number types. You said that n is some `Integral` (specifically, Integer in this case). `k <- [0..n]` means that k is the same `Integral` type. Then you use the `/` division, which is part of the `Fractional` class. Which means your result would have to be both `Integral` and `Fractional`, and I don't think such a type exists.

The solution would be to convert k to your result type before using it with `fromIntegral k`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advocate for this signature:

```
piApprox :: (Fractional r) => Int -> r
```

The reason being, the "precision" parameter doesn't have any particular "value" meaning, it's just a counter of how many steps you're willing to let the function run. (A better approach might be specifying what *deviation* to the true value *π* you want to allow instead of the evaluation depth, but that's more complicated.)

Next, the point where your currect implementation clashes is actually `(-1)^k` (it requires `Integral` because the exponentiation is implemented by recursed multiplication). Yes, that's the usual way to denote an alternating sign in maths and science, but if you think about it it's a pretty bad way. You're not really interested in powers here, just in the sign-alternation, and that's far more naturally achieved with `cycle [1, -1]`.

For the multiplication it's different, that doesn't need `Integral` at all but requires that both arguments have the *same* type. The natural way to achieve this is, use a `Fractional` variable right away, rather than converting from a integral one! So instead of `[0..n]`, you could use `[0 .. fromIntegral n]`. Just one conversion instead of one *at each step*.

Actually though, it's better not to bound the indices at all! Since this is Haskell, you can define the list as infinite (like what `cycle` also does). Of course you can't sum an infinite list, but you can simply trim it down right before doing so:

```
piApprox :: (Fractional r) => Int -> r
piApprox n = 4 * sum (take n [ σ / (2*k + 1) | (σ,k) <- zip (cycle [-1,1]) [0..] ])
```

Or, perhaps nicer written with the [`ParallelListComprehensions` extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html):

```
piApprox n = (4 *) . sum $
    take n [ σ / (2*k + 1) | σ <- cycle [1, -1]
                           | k <- [0..]
           ]
```

This does one step less than your implementation because `take n [0..]` is equivalent to `[0..n-1]`. I suppose this doesn't matter too much, otherwise it's trivial to fix.

---

Finally: I assume you're aware that this formula is pretty bad in terms of convergence speed!